# renaming the files recursively in unix

Tags: unix, rename, ksh, mv, hp-ux

i know this would be marked as a duplicate one, but i tried searching google and what i'm trying is not working for me.

I've some `.txt` files in a directory, i need to rename all the `*.txt` files to `*_XYZ.txt` recursively. XYZ is defined in a variable `X`.

I've tried below code:

```
file=`find ./ -type f -name "*.txt"|sed "s,^./,,g" |awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`

for i in "$file"
do
mv "$i" "$i_${X}.txt"
done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script destroys original filenames in variable `file`, this is why it cannot rename files.

Working example:

```
X="_XYZ"
for f in $(find . -type f ! -name "*$X.txt" -name "*.txt"); do 
    mv "$f" "${f%.txt}$X.txt"
done
```

Output:

```
$ X="_XYZ"
$ find . -type f -name "*.txt"
./c_XYZ.txt
./aa/c.txt
./a.txt
./b.txt
$ for f in $(find . -type f ! -name "*$X.txt" -name "*.txt"); do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}$X.txt"; done
$ find . -type f -name "*.txt"
./b_XYZ.txt
./c_XYZ.txt
./aa/c_XYZ.txt
./a_XYZ.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Maxim:-) .It worked. i was just messed up in the `mv` part.can you please elaborate the command please.

Comment: @User123 `${f%.txt}` chops off trailing `.txt` from variable `f`. See https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html for more details.